# Media Query not responding in different sizes

Tags: html, css

My media queries are not showing up properly. Here are the codes. When I am seeing it on my monitor it's fine. But when on laptop, it is not fine. Even when I try to lessen the width of the page it's not responsive but when I do it on inspect, it shows it's fine. How do I create a media query which makes my website responsive to all devices?

```
    /* css variables */
:root {
  --white: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  --blue: rgb(137, 184, 234);
  --black: rgb(70, 70, 70);
}
```

https://codepen.io/rubinaramesh199/pen/mdOEKpw

Comment: waiting for your HTML and CSS code.

Comment: That's unreadable, please edit the question and include the code there.

Comment: I am not able to post the media query. Says it's too long.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since your media query is totally unreadable I made this simple example to show you how media query works.

First I would follow the mobile-first approach which means. I will design everything for mobile size and make it fit and change it as I go up in screen sizes.

Therefore you will see `p` element design outside the media query since it is going to work from `0px` till the next `break-point` I make which is  `min-width: 768px` and that means the `font-size` and `background-color` will change at this point which is `768px` and above till it reach the next `break-point` which is `992px` and will change the `font-size` and `background-color` as well.

Till it hit the next `break-point` and so on. The last `break-point` which is at the bottom will be your last query and it will apply the styles from  `1400px` and above no matter how large the screen is and that media will override the media before it.

Here is a great article about media queries. [media-queries](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-media-queries/) and here is another link from the MDN website [media_queries MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```css
p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  p {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  p {
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: blueviolet;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  p {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    background-color: aqua;
  }
}

@media screen and(min-width: 1400px) {
  p {
    font-size: 4rem;
    background-color: brown;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque voluptatum minus eum ipsa dicta accusantium atque aut impedit nulla aliquid incidunt voluptas repellat aperiam tempora praesentium, rerum omnis blanditiis quam!
</p>
```

---

Edit

yeah fixing that is really hard. you should have a media query that works from `(min-width: 1601px` and beyond to keep the styles you built.

What you are doing in your code is simply applying styles between let's say `375px` and `413px` only and then in your second query you are making changes between yet again another two points. and making so much redundant code.

applying styles between two points is totally fine as long as you know what you are doing and changing. (min-width) and (max-width) but that means your styles and changes are only stuck between these two points and will not be applied to the rest of your code.

Anyway. to keep your last changes it should be only `min-width` and that will apply from that point you specify to the largest screen possible.

I highly recommend reading the two articles I added above and rebuild your project. it will make you better.

also, I made some changes including reordering your query since order matters.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 413px)
@media screen and (min-width: 414px) and (max-width: 767px) 
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)
@media screen and (min-width: 992px)
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px)
```

there are some errors of course since your media is just conflicting with each other. But rebuilding and following the mobile-first approach will save you time.

Sorry I wasn't able to help you completely.

Comment: I have posted my codepen link. Thanks for the clarity. Let me give it a try.

Comment: "I'm afraid you've found a page that doesn't exist on CodePen." :(

Comment: you have helped me a lot. Appreciate it.. let will work on that now. Will revert. Thanks for this clarity.